# The conference doesnt work in twilio

Tags: twilio, phone-call

I implemented conference call in Twilio, but it doesn't work. The error is:

> Error: 11200 HTTP retrieval failure

In more details :

> 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.

Code:

```
string AccountSid = "...";
string AuthToken = ".....";
var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
string appversion = twilio.ApiVersion;
ArrayList participants = new ArrayList();
// participants.Add("+972599223072");
participants.Add(txtphone1.Text);
participants.Add(txtphone2.Text);
participants.Add(txtphone3.Text);
participants.Add(txtphone4.Text);
participants.Add(txtphone5.Text);
participants.Add(txtphone6.Text);
participants.Add(txtphone7.Text);
// Go through the participants array and call each person.
foreach (string user in participants)
    {
    if (user != "")
        {
        var options = new CallOptions();
        options.Url = "http://sandbox4.eureeca.com/Conference/conference.xml";
        options.To = user;
        options.From = "+97243741357";
        options.Method = "POST";
        options.Record = true;

        //   options.StatusCallback = "/2010-04-01/Accounts/" + AccountSid + "/Calls";
        var call = twilio.InitiateOutboundCall(options);

        Console.WriteLine(call.Sid);
        }
```

Code END

```
Conference.xml content :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Response>
  <Say>Joining a conference room</Say>
  <Dial>

    <Conference>MyConference</Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: Now sure exactly how the API is supposed to work, but aren't you trying to make Twilio POST to an XML file? You may want to change `options.Method` to `GET` instead of `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

Looks like you're TwiML is in a static XML file?  Its pretty common for web servers to not allow POST requests to static files.  You can either reconfigure your web server to allow this, or change the CallOptions `Method` property to `GET' to tell Twilio to make a GET request for the file rather than a POST.

Hope that helps.